# nginx connect to socket failed no file or directory with django and uwsgi

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-14.04, django, uwsgi

I am trying to deploy a django web app using nginx and uwsgi using this tutorial : [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04).

I followed the tutorial step by step and these are my configuration files:

/etc/uwsgi/sites/picknbox.ini:

[uwsgi]

```
project = picknbox    # Virtual environment name in home directory
base = /home/picknbox    # Home directory path

chdir = /home/picknbox/picknbox/picknbox     # Virtual Env Directory
home = /home/picknbox/picknbox       #Django Project Directory with manage.py$
module = picknbox.wsgi:application     # project name

master = true
processes = 5

socket = /home/picknbox/picknbox/picknbox/picknbox.sock
chmod-socket = 664
vacuum = true
```

/etc/init/uwsgi.conf:

```
description "uWSGI application server in Emperor mode"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

setuid picknbox
setgid www-data

exec /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/picknbox:

```
upstream django {
    server unix:/home/picknbox/picknbox/picknbox/picknbox.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name picknbox.com; # IP Address or FQDN

    location /static/ {
        root /home/picknbox/picknbox/picknbox;
    }

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/home/picknbox/picknbox/picknbox/picknbox.sock;
    }
}
```

But i am getting a 502 gateway error.
Nginx log :

```
2016/06/12 11:46:58 [crit] 10313#0: *15 connect() to unix:/home/picknbox/pickbox/picknbox/picknbox.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 162.220.220.85, server: picknbox.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/home/picknbox/picknbox/picknbox/picknbox.sock:", host: "picknbox.com"
```

How can i solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

You should check with `ps` command if the application server is running. If not, you need to start it with `service` command.